# Stuck entering Recovery mode plus Power and Home Button not working

Tags: recovery-mode, buttons

My phone is Samsung Galaxy J Max Tab (SM-T285YD). My phone's power and home buttons are not working. Now somehow i entered into recovery mode. But while entering it got stuck. What should i do now. It is stuck in this stage. [image]

Comment: your buttons are wet/short circuited. dry smartphone in sun